# How do I send a REST request in Kafka without using confluent platform?

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to run kafka connect in distributed mode. Is REST the only way to start the connector? Otherwise, what commands should i use ?

Comment: Your title is misleading and does not reflect your question. Please amend it.

Answer (score 0):

The Kafka Connect API is part of Apache Kafka. You can run it standalone, or as part of [Confluent Platform](https://www.confluent.io/download/).

Information on how to configure it is [here](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect). If you are using distributed mode, you have to use the [REST API](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect_rest) to configure it.